# ¿Cómo puedo comparar dos variables archivadas en la base de datos de MySQL con una sentencia condicional?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, condiciones, formato-condicional

¡Hola comunidad!

Ante todo gracias por vuestras respuestas. ¡Sois de gran utilidad!

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en la que comparo el valor de una variable con los valores de otras variables, una que hace de límite inferior y otra de límite superior y que devuelve un cuadro que cambia de color según la comparativa **verde** cuando la variable comparada es inferior a la variable de comparación, **rojo** cuando es superior y **amarillo** si no cumple ninguna de las clausulas anteriores, es decir, está entre los dos valores de las variables que hacen de límite, porque tiene un valor ni inferior ni superior.

Cuando lo hago con números, funciona perfectamente, como se puede ver en el código, pero mi problema viene cuando trato de cambiar los valores numéricos por las variables `$b` (valor bajo que sustituiría al 15) y `$a` (valor alto que sustituiría al 200).

Como os comento, con los números funciona bien, varía a verde, rojo o amarillo en función del valor de la variable de comparación almacenada en `mysql`. Mi idea era que, en función de los valores que se introdujeran en `$b` o en `$a` y comparando con la otra variable, se ejecutara la sentencia `if` del código.

¿Se podría hacer lo mismo comparando con las variables mencionadas? ¡Gracias!

```
<?php

//Conexión a la base de datos//

include_once ('php/conexion.php');

//Filtros//

include_once ('php/filtros.php');

//Variables mes//

include_once ('php/variables.php');

include_once ('php/variable.php');

?>

<?php
// perform MySQL Query (MySQLi or PDO)
// get results: $result, make a decision based on the condition
// will use MySQLi for example
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "insectocaptores");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
  exit();
}

//Variables de comparación a incluir en la comparativa if. Esto es lo que no consigo incluir en la 
sentencia` if y que funcione correctamente//

//$b = $mysqli->query("SELECT sum(Bajo) FROM insectocaptores Group by Year(Fecha)")//


//$a= $mysqli->query("SELECT sum(Alto) FROM insectocaptores Group by Year(Fecha)");//

//Esta sentencia funciona correctamente y ejecuta los resultados esperados//
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT sum(Moscas) FROM insectocaptores Group by Year(Fecha)")) {
   while($prueba = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     if( $prueba['sum(Moscas)'] < 15 ){
       $colorClass = "greenBox";
     }
     elseif( $prueba['sum(Moscas)'] > 200 )  {
       $colorClass = "redBox";
     }
     else {
       $colorClass = "yellowBox";
     }
   }
   $result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Learn Make Graphic with PHP</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
        .container {
            width: 50%;
            margin: 15px auto;
        }
    </style>

<style>
.myBox {
  position:absolute;
  left:471px;
  top:94px;
  width:204px;
  height:183px;
  filter:alpha(opacity=90);
  opacity:0.90;
  z-index:7;
}

.greenBox {
  background: green;
}

.yellowBox {
  background: yellow;
}

.redBox {
  background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--Filtros de selección de los datos de la gráfica-->
<form method='post' action='cajas.php'> 
Seleccione el año:<br /> 
<select name='Fecha'> 
<option></option>
<option <?php if($Fecha=="2018") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2018</option> 
<option <?php if($Fecha=="2017") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2017</option> 
<option <?php if($Fecha=="2016") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2016</option> 
<option <?php if($Fecha=="2015") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2015</option>
</select>
<br /> 
<input type='submit' value='Buscar' /> 
</form>
<div id="wb_Shape6" class="myBox <?php echo $colorClass; ?>">
  <img src="images/img0012.png" id="Shape6" alt="" style="width:204px;height:183px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no funciona porque tanto `$a` como `$b` serían resultados de consultas SQL. Pero esos resultados necesitarían ser leídos con alguno de los métodos `fetch`  existentes para hacer la comparación posterior.

De todos modos, para este caso no necesitas hacer `N` consultas para hacer comparaciones, sino que **puedes integrar todo en una sola consulta**.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
SELECT total, a, b,
  CASE
    WHEN total < a THEN 'greenBox'
    WHEN total > b THEN 'redBox'
    ELSE 'yellowBox'
  END as color
FROM (
        SELECT 
          SUM(Alto) AS a,
          SUM(Bajo) AS b,
          SUM(Moscas) AS total
        FROM insectocaptores 
        GROUP BY Year(Fecha)
      ) AS t ;
```

Esa consulta tomará los valores `a` y `b` directamente para poder compararlos en los `CASE`.

Para integrarlo en tu código sería simplemente esto:

```
#Nuestra nueva consulta
$sql="SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN total < a THEN 'greenBox'
    WHEN total > b THEN 'redBox'
    ELSE 'yellowBox'
  END as color
FROM (
        SELECT 
          SUM(Alto) AS a,
          SUM(Bajo) AS b,
          SUM(Moscas) AS total
        FROM insectocaptores 
        GROUP BY Year(Fecha)
      ) AS t";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
   while($prueba = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       #Tomarías el valor directamente del resultado sin más...
       $colorClass = $prueba['color'];
   }
   $result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

### Algunas notas

1. La lógica actual haría que, si hay varias filas en los resultados el valor de `$colorClass` se quede con el valor de la última fila. Entonces: si esperas varias filas debes modificar la lógica en el código; si esperas una sola fila conviene poner un `LIMIT 1` en la consulta SQL y en ese caso no haría falta leer los datos en un `while`. Esto se aleja del problema inicial planteado, pero es algo que deberías tener en cuenta.
2. En tu código falta decidir qué debe ocurrir si no hay resultados. Por ejemplo, ¿debería `$colorClass` en ese caso tener un valor por defecto? Si es así entonces deberías declarar la variable de entrada con ese valor por defecto. Como ves, hay un limbo con respecto a esa variable que deberías resolver en tu código.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, A. Cedano. Sin ánimo de querer abusar y dado que, como ves, no domino el lenguaje php, ¿podrías indicarme como insertar tu código en el código php que he presentado? Gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: @RubénJoséOlivaresPuertas he puesto un ejemplo de implementación contextual.

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaración A. Cedano. Voy a probarlo en mi código y a corregir posibles errores. ¡Saludos!